# How to split huge CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 40k rows and 1 column because all the data is separated by semicolons.

```
insert_date;currency_from;currency_to;currency_value
0   2017-01-02 00:00:00.000;EUR;TL;3.7073
1   2017-01-02 00:00:00.000;USD;TL;3.5445
2   2017-01-02 00:00:00.000;GBP;TL;4.3510
3   2017-01-02 00:00:00.000;BTC;USD;0.0000
4   2017-01-02 00:00:00.000;EUR;USD;1.0459
```

This is what my data looks like as a pandas dataframe. I want to split on the semicolon to make separate columns.

Comment: Specify the delimiter as `";"` (the semicolon character) when creating a `csv.reader` (or `csv.DictReader`) — both of which will allow you to read the file a row at a time. See the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas, this is done with the `sep` parameter per [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', sep=';')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you would like to have a list of dicts?

```
import csv

with open('your/path/to/your/file.csv') as f:
    data = [i for i in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')

process_your_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using str.spilt()

Syntax: Series.str.split(pat=None, n=-1, expand=False)
Parameters:

pat: String value, separator or delimiter to separate string at.
n: Numbers of max separations to make in a single string, default is -1 which means all.
expand: Boolean value, returns a data frame with different value in different columns if True. Else it returns a series with list of strings.